How to add defs g in svg, using C# code in blazor webasssembly
I want to insert a <defs><g> tag in an SVG using C# code in a Blazor WebAssembly Razor file, but it's not working. I used RenderFragment to add a simple <rect>; by clicking on the SVG, it works. However, when I try to add <defs><g> using the same method, it fails. In the browser's debug mode, it appears correct, but the <defs><g> won't display. Here is my code:
@using BlazorSvgApp.Client.Model
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<svg class="station" width="800" height="600" tab-index="0" @onmouseup="OnSvgMouseUp">
    <defs>
        <g id="combinedGraphic">
            <rect width="16" height="16" x="00" y="0" fill="green" />
            <circle cx="28" cy="8" r="8" fill="green" />
        </g>
    </defs>

    @for (int i = 0; i < _fragments.Count; i++)
    {
        @_fragments[i](_models[i])
    }

    <use xlink:href="#combinedGraphic" x="100" y="100"/>
    <use xlink:href="#combinedGraphic" x="100" y="200"/>
    <use xlink:href="#combinedGraphic" x="100" y="300"/>
</svg>

@code {
    private readonly List<RenderFragment<GraphicModel>> _fragments = new();
    private readonly List<GraphicModel> _models = new();

    private void OnSvgMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var graphicModel = new GraphicModel { X = e.OffsetX, Y = e.OffsetY };
        var rectModel = new GraphicModel { X = e.OffsetX + 50, Y = e.OffsetY };
        RenderFragment<GraphicModel> fragment = model =>@<use xlink:href="#combinedGraphic" x="@model.X" y="@model.Y" />;
        RenderFragment<GraphicModel> fragment1 = model =>@<rect width="16" height="16" fill="green" x="@model.X" y="@model.Y" />;

        _models.Add(graphicModel);
        _fragments.Add(fragment);

        _models.Add(rectModel);
        _fragments.Add(fragment1);
    }
}


And here is the elements in browser:
enter image description here
When I move the mouse over elements, the <use> tag for the created elements displays "0,0", which I believe is the source of the issue.
enter image description here

displays 0,0 usually indicates a namespace issue. Try adding the svg namespace to the svg element.

thanks alot, this is the problem, i can fix this
